# SQL Server : error in covert varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 18.

This is my code

```
select * 
from Table
where convert(numeric, ["신규가입자수"] ) > 100
```

Column (신규가입자수)'s content is number, and it's data type is `varchar(50)` like below.

| "Date" (varchar) | "신규가입자수" (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| "2018-07-18" | "2194" |
| "2018-07-17" | "2123" |

I think it is very simple code, but it doesn't work.

None of them converted not only numeric but also int, float etc..

Even when I tried to import csv file and set that column as number, it failed to import as number, only successfully imported when it goes `varchar`.

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is your choice of data types for your columns. Fix that, fix the problem. I also hope your values (like your column) don't *really* have double quotes around them. If they do then your data is effectively ruined. You'd be better off starting again and fixing your design and data. Having a column with double quotes in its name is a poor design choice. Double quotes are the ANSI delimit identifier so a having a column called `"MyColumnName"` is really confusing.

Comment: @woohi . . . Your question is unclear.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what?  Is the query not doing what you expect?  If so, what is it doing and what do you expect?

Comment: `it failed to import as number`. Check your CSV file. It means you have non-numeric data in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the converted value in the result set, then you need to select it:

```
select t.*,
       convert(numeric, t.["신규가입자수"] ) as converted_value
from Table t
where convert(numeric, ["신규가입자수"] ) > 100;
```

If you are getting an error, use `try_convert()` instead:

```
select t.*,
       try_convert(numeric, t.["신규가입자수"] ) as converted_value
from Table t
where try_convert(numeric, ["신규가입자수"] ) > 100;
```

If the issue is the double quotes, then remove them:

```
select t.*,
       try_convert(numeric, replace(t.["신규가입자수"], '"', '') ) as converted_value
from Table t
where try_convert(numeric, replace(["신규가입자수"], '"', '') ) > 100;
```

Comment: The problem was double quotes. I thought double quotes was just showing expression in result, but it wasn't at all. As you say, i removed double quotes and it works now.